# Issue with writing spark stream into Mongodb sink

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to write a datafram into Mongodb sink using foreachbach in Pyspark but getting an error. I am using spark version 2.4.7 and python 3.7. the same code work fine when I tried to write the datafram as batch. I used mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.1
this is the code and the error message:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master('local[3]') \
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.1') \
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.7') \
    .getOrCreate()

def mongoSink(df, batch_id):
    df.write \
    .format('mongo') \
    .mode('append') \
    .option('spark.mongodb.output.uri', 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db.cl') \
    .save()

schema = StructType([....])

# Reading from Kafka topic
kafka_df = spark.readStream \
        .format('kafka') \
        .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', 'localhost:9092') \
        .option('subscribe', 'kTopic') \
        .option('startingOffsets', 'latest') \
        .load()

    # Processing code 
.
.
.

# Writing to MongoDB
write_df_mongodb = f_df.writeStream \
        .format('mongo') \
        .foreachBatch(mongoSink) \
        .option("checkpointLocation", "chk_dir") \
        .outputMode('append') \
        .start()

write_df_mongodb.awaitTermination()
```

Error message:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o77.awaitTermination.
: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: An exception was raised by the Python Proxy. Return Message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Spark2-4\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 2381, in _call_proxy
    return_value = getattr(self.pool[obj_id], method)(*params)
  File "D:\Spark2-4\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 191, in call
    raise e
  File "D:\Spark2-4\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 188, in call
    self.func(DataFrame(jdf, self.sql_ctx), batch_id)
  File "<ipython-input-5-e9393e49a072>", line 5, in mongoSink
    .option('spark.mongodb.output.uri', 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db.cl') \
  File "D:\Spark2-4\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 737, in save
    self._jwrite.save()
  File "D:\Spark2-4\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "D:\Spark2-4\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "D:\Spark2-4\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o83.save.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/ConnectionString
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.MongoCompanionConfig$$anonfun$4.apply(MongoCompanionConfig.scala:278)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.MongoCompanionConfig$$anonfun$4.apply(MongoCompanionConfig.scala:278)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.MongoCompanionConfig$class.connectionString(MongoCompanionConfig.scala:278)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.WriteConfig$.connectionString(WriteConfig.scala:37)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.WriteConfig$.apply(WriteConfig.scala:239)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.WriteConfig$.apply(WriteConfig.scala:37)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.MongoCompanionConfig$class.apply(MongoCompanionConfig.scala:124)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.WriteConfig$.apply(WriteConfig.scala:37)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.MongoCompanionConfig$class.apply(MongoCompanionConfig.scala:113)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.WriteConfig$.apply(WriteConfig.scala:37)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.ConnectionString
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
```

Pleas any help
Thank you,

Comment: : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/ConnectionString
seems like a dependency conflict to me. Check the dependency tree.